# Blend в Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Как запустить *blend* в *Visual Studio 2013 Pro*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blend - это отдельное приложение, которое устанавливается вместе со студией. У вас на него должен быть отдельный ярлык в меню - Blend for Visual Studio 2013. Который указывает на

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Blend.exe"
```